# Case statement character classification

Tags: ruby

I am trying to classify characters using a case statement, but I am not sure how I would go about this in Ruby.

Here is what I have:

```
  case c
  when ('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'), '$'
    puts "#{c} true"
  when ' '
    #ignore spaces
  else
    puts "#{c} false"
  end
```

But this is kind of messy and I'd like to simplify it. Is there anyway to simplify this with a regular expression?

Something like:

```
  case c
  when '[a-zA-Z$]'
    puts "#{c} true"
  when '[\s]'
    #ignore whitespace
  else
    puts "#{c} false"
  end
```

How would something like this be done in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely! But the syntax should be like this:

```
case c
when /[a-zA-Z$]/
  puts "#{c} true"
when /\s/
  # ignore
else
  puts "#{c} false"
end
```

Comment: Sweet! this is exactly what I was looking/hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: You answered too quick :), I have to wait another 9 minutes to accept.